# Ruby on Rails Switch

Tags: ruby, switch-statement

Can someone provide an example on how to use switch case in Ruby for variable?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I assume you refer to case/when.

```
case a_variable # a_variable is the variable we want to compare
when 1    #compare to 1
  puts "it was 1" 
when 2    #compare to 2
  puts "it was 2"
else
  puts "it was something else"
end
```

or

```
puts case a_variable
when 1
  "it was 1"
when 2
  "it was 2"
else
  "it was something else"
end
```

EDIT

Something that maybe not everyone knows about but what can be very useful is that you can use regexps in a case statement.

```
foo = "1Aheppsdf"

what = case foo
when /^[0-9]/
  "Begins with a number"
when /^[a-zA-Z]/
  "Begins with a letter"
else
  "Begins with something else"
end
puts "String: #{what}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I replace a_variable with params[:id] right?

Comment: Absolutely, just make sure you are comparing variables of the same type, e.g "1" is not equal to 1. However "1".to_i is equal to 1 (to_i converts a string to an integer). If you want to compare params[:id] with an integer you need to do "case params[:id].to_i". It looks a bit strange to me to test params[:id] with "case", are you sure about what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks mate. That was really helpful. I think that was the problem!

Comment: There are some differences from a traditional switch..case.  The most notable being there is no cascading onto the next item.  Another being that you can list multiple (comma separated) items in each `when`.  Lastly, they don't just match on equality, they match on the `===` operator, so: `String === "thing"` is true, therefore `when String then whatever` would be matched.

Comment: **Important:** Unlike `switch` statements in many other languages, Ruby’s `case` does NOT have [**fall-through**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough), so there is no need to end each `when` with a `break`.