# Conditional <div> tags inside the view. Why bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

In my rails app I have a very dynamic user dashboard that shows and hides div elements based on the users role (customer, employee, admin).

For example: users/show.html.erb

```
 <% if current_user.role_id == 4 %>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <% elsif current_user.role_id == 1 %>
    <th>Cancel Appointment</th>
    <% else %>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

I stored the table nav tabs inside their own partials like this:

```
<% if current_user.role_id == 1 %>
<%= render 'users/customer_bar' %>
<% elsif current_user.role_id == 2 %>
<%= render 'users/employee_bar' %>
<% elsif current_user.role_id == 4 %>
<%= render 'users/honcho_bar' %>
```

The same could be done for the aforementioned tags but that would not at all be DRY. Is there a better way? Why is it bad to conditionally format tags in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Statement**

Maybe you're looking for [`case / switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603362/ruby-on-rails-switch):

```
case current_user.role_id
when 4
  #do something for 4 
when 1
  #do something for 1
end
```

--

**System**

I would highly recommend using a `partial` to get this to work:

```
<%= render partial: "your_partial", local: { your_local_var: "value" } %>
```

This will allow you to define the conditions in the partial itself:

```
#app/views/controller/your_partial.html.erb
<% if var == "value" %>
  ...
<% else %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

---

**Bad?**

I wouldn't say it's "bad" for the sake of it - it's typically the case that you'll need conditions. The issue, I think, is you need to ensure you're able to handle the conditions in the most effective way.

Using `case / switch` would be a legitimate way of doing this, however, you may have an issue further up the `stack`